# Replicated values in array

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to check all the account names from a table, then store them to a string array.

At the moment this is what I'm using to do so:

```
for(int Rowi = 0; Rowi < rowCount + 1; Rowi ++){
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT AccountName FROM accounts WHERE AccountID = " + Rowi);
            while(rs.next()){
                String test = rs.getString("AccountName");
                System.out.println("asd: " + test);
                accounts[Rowi] = test;                  
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i ++){
            System.out.println("SAVED INFO: " + accounts[rowCount]);
        }
```

And this is the results that I get:

```
asd: FatalMind 
asd: Shurin
asd: test
SAVED INFO: test
SAVED INFO: test
SAVED INFO: test
```

I don't get why it's properly pulling each record row by row, but not saving it like I tell it to, it only saves the last value in all of the indexes. Clearly I'm not doing something right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last loop you need to index the accounts array with `i`, not `rowCount`.

So change

```
System.out.println("SAVED INFO: " + accounts[rowCount]);
```

to

```
System.out.println("SAVED INFO: " + accounts[i]);
                                            ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `rowCount` doesn't change in your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i ++){
    System.out.println("SAVED INFO: " + accounts[rowCount]);
}
```

I'm assuming `rowCount` corresponds to the last index.  So you're telling it to print the value at the last index three times.  (Or, more specifically, `rowCount` number of times.)

I assume you meant to use `i` instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i ++){
    System.out.println("SAVED INFO: " + accounts[i]);
}
```